# Dropdown list value is not binding to the model in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind dropdown value back to the respective model property, but it's not binding.

Even after selecting value from the above dropdown, `Model.batchVM.CourseName` in controller is empty.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

This is my markup:

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.batchVM.ClientName" value="@Model.clientDetailsVM.UserName" />
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label asp-for="@Model.batchVM.CourseName" class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6">
            <select id="CourseName" name="CourseName" asp-for="@Model.batchVM.CourseName" class="form-select">
                <option value="">-- Select a Course --</option>
                @foreach (var courseList in Model.CourseListVM)
                {
                    <option value="@courseList.CourseId">@courseList.CourseName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.batchVM.CourseName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Batch" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```